# How to print canvas element by using javascript print method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

How can I print a created canvas element that has some content drawn on it using javascript? My print preview shows a blank box instead of the contents in the canvas element?

First i create my canvas image by using html2canvas, then i see that image is created. But i couldn't print the div which includes related image.

In **IE** i can see it when triggered button twice. In first click it opens blank print preview, in second click it opens it with related content. However in **chrome** it opens blank content at once, it cannot load second trigger; page freezes.

Here is my code;

```
function printDiv(index) {
var canvasImg = "";
var divToPrint = document.getElementById('hr'+index);
html2canvas(divToPrint, {
onrendered: function(canvas) {
var canvasImg = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
$('#seckinCanvas').html('<img src="'+canvasImg+'" alt="">');
}
});

var printContent = document.getElementById("seckinCanvas");
var windowUrl = '';
var uniqueName = new Date();
var windowName = 'Print' + uniqueName.getTime();
var printWindow = window.open(windowUrl, windowName,'left=500,top=500,width=0,height=0');
printWindow.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
printWindow.document.close();
printWindow.focus();
printWindow.print();
printWindow.close();
}
```

Comment: Try it after commenting printWindow.close(); There is some issue with chrome.

Comment: I have tried but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 9):

Here's what worked for me (no JS needed):

1. Include a print button in the HTML:

   ```
   <a id="btn-print" onclick="print()">Print</a>
   ```
2. Add this to your CSS:

   ```
   @media print {
     // Make all your non-canvas things (divs and stuff) disappear:
     .notCanvas, .alsoNotCanvas, ... {
       display: none;
     }
     // Center your canvas (optional):
     canvas {
       padding: 0;
       margin: auto;
       display: block;
       position: absolute;
       width: 800px;
       height: 800px;
       top: 0;
       bottom: 0;
       left: 0;
       right: 0;
     }
   }
   ```

This lets you print just the canvas. 
I didn't cross-browser test this, but it definitely works in Chrome.

Comment: This should be **cross-browser supported**, according to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries). Also, if you'd like to hide all elements but a few, you can use the `:not()` pseudo-class: `:not(.canvas_element):not(.element_that_should_remain_visible) {display: none;}`

Comment: I needed a JS solution so [this worked for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66766329/3645855)